# Unable to access WordPress admin panel

Tags: wp-admin

Yesterday, I noted that only the home page of [workcosec.com](https://workcosec.com) properly visible. If I tried to access a blog post, there was a message of critical error.

Through FTP, I renamed plugin folder to plugins in order to disable plugins. Next, the blog posts then visible.

However, unable to access WP Admin panel.
Getting this message:

There has been a critical error on this website (https://www.canva.com/design/DAFRKs...share&utm_medium=link2&utm_source=sharebutton).

After trying to access WP admin panel through http://www.workcosec.com/wp-admin, I accessed error log. Showing Apache error: https://www.canva.com/design/DAFRLO...share&utm_medium=link2&utm_source=sharebutton

Got in touch on Plesk Forum and one expert reply was this problem is not Plesk issue.

Also, I have removed a W3 cache directory that was showing on the root directory (I mean this was showing along with WP-content directory and other directories) while on FTP (FileZilla). This is because I remember once getting a message while accessing WP admin that included mention of W3 cache plugin as causing the issue.

Also relevant could be this [email alert by Semrush site audit](https://www.canva.com/design/DAFRQHfxzw0/bCQtv-gPilLlrxAtXjzplw/view?utm_content=DAFRQHfxzw0&utm_campaign=designshare&utm_medium=link2&utm_source=sharebutton).

Comment: "There has been a critical error on this website" - this should have both emailed you the detailed error message and written it to the server error logs. Can you find either one? I'm not sure what you mean by showing apache error: it should be an error from PHP with a detailed error message and call stack, either there in the apache logs or in your WordPress debug.log in the wp-content folder if you've enabled that, or in a separate PHP error log if you've got that set up.

Comment: Here is the screenshot of logs: https://www.canva.com/design/DAFRQu6rWi0/53BUCQVl7YQNdFA0sfj08Q/view?utm_content=DAFRQu6rWi0&utm_campaign=designshare&utm_medium=link2&utm_source=sharebutton      Here is more detail: Unable to display the file /var/www/vhosts/workcosec.com/httpdocs/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/cropped-WC-192x192.png: Unsupported file format.

Comment: Also this screenshot might help: https://www.canva.com/design/DAFRQoFj5QI/8E1lJtwivUFr27R8kaowPw/view?utm_content=DAFRQoFj5QI&utm_campaign=designshare&utm_medium=link2&utm_source=sharebutton

Comment: There are only access logs in the screenshot. Can you find the error log for the time you got the critical error? It will probably start "PHP Fatal Error". The Unsupported File Format one is a browser error and won't break the dashboard.

Comment: https://www.canva.com/design/DAFRQ9aw3jA/bP_s6dzUcgDIUQOkHDXzDA/view?utm_content=DAFRQ9aw3jA&utm_campaign=designshare&utm_medium=link2&utm_source=sharebutton

Comment: OK: the problem is your wp-content/db.php is trying to call wp_kses(), but that hasn't been loaded yet: you can see that db.php is loaded on [line 124 of wp-settings.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6.0-branch/wp-settings.php#L124) but kses not until [line 217](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6.0-branch/wp-settings.php#L217). Where did db.php come from? What's it for?

Comment: @Rup Yes, I can track db.php file. I do not remember how it originated. Is it safe to delete it since db.php not part of core WordPress? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZGINg_uFYW3GdeUOzAIMLPFD-jvMc3dV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It looks like db.php was only using wp_kses to report an error, so there was already something else wrong. You won't be getting exactly the same error if you've removed db.php but if you're getting a different one I'd guess there is something wrong with your installation. Up to you: either chase down the next error, or try rebuilding the site: take a copy of your database and wp-content/uploads then set up a new WordPress on a different server with fresh copies of WordPress itself and your plugins until you find something that breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You might try renaming the folder that contains your current theme. That should get you back to a default 'Twenty-xxx' theme, and then troubleshoot from there.

Initial thoughts are perhaps some external call via your theme to the Canva site, so that's why you might try disabling the current theme by renaming it's folder.

Comment: I have renamed current theme folder as well plugin folder. Still getting the same critical error message. Also renamed db.php file. But same critical error message.

Comment: I would next manually reinstall WP (via FTP). Then I would look at all folders for files that don't have the date/timestamp of the latest WP files. It's possible there are some 'rouge' files in there. You might also manually install your theme and plugins (not via Update, but download files, extract, then upload via FTP). And check your htaccess file in the root (and anywhere else you find one).
You may also need to export everything into a new WP installation.

Answer (score -1):

Did you checked the permissions as well?

Make sure it is as follows:

- wp-admin: 744
- wp-content: 744
- wp-content/themes: 744
- wp-content/plugins: 744
- wp-content/uploads: 744
- wp-config.php: 764
- .htaccess: 764

Also,Try to rename the .htaccess file ,and load your site

Comment: I have started with a new WordPress instance connected with finsure.com. Next, the objective is to migrate only the blog posts.

It is to be noted that in the front end, blog posts are not showing up (instead, error message: There has been a critical error on this website). Only the home page showing of workcosec.com.

Any tips on migrating the content of blog posts appreciated.